# How to Always show my app icon in System Tray using C# in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, registry, system-tray

I have and windows app and I want that my app icon will always show in system tray. As now it will hide after time. Please help me to solve my problem. Thanks in advance.

```
Code of System tray App: 
NotifyIcon ni = new NotifyIcon();
// Put the icon in the system tray and allow it react to mouse clicks.          
ni.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(ni_MouseClick);
ni.Icon = Resources.favicon;
ni.Text = "***";
ni.Visible = true;

// Attach a context menu.
ni.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenus().Create(ni);

ni.BalloonTipText = "abc...";
ni.BalloonTipTitle = "abc";
ni.ShowBalloonTip(5000);
```

Comment: Please let us know how to reproduce this

Comment: I didn't get you..? As the icon in system tray  get hidden after some time.I want that it is always available there in the system tray..!!!!!! Only balloon get hide...!!!!!!

Comment: This is not possible of course, all programmers would do this since they all think their program is Most Important.  Which would make the feature entirely useless.  Only the user can do this.  So can you.  Click on the overflow arrow and click Customize.  Change the "Behaviors" setting for your icon to "Show icon and notifications".

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for your response. Is there any way that I can customize the icons through the code??

Comment: @user2458153 I already answered that question

Comment: Speaking as a user, I can confirm that I don't want you to do that.  Read: [There is no interface for preventing your notification icon from being hidden](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/15/10105142.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I guessing a little, but I think the issue is that the user has chosen a UI option that hides notification icons to avoid the notification area taking over the taskbar.

There is no supported way for you the programmer to indicate that your notification icon is so important that it must show all the time irrespective of the wishes of the user. The user gets the opportunity to indicate that certain icons are always to be shown. Right click in the notification area and select *Customize notification icons*. This allows the user to decide which icons are always visible.

So, you the programmer do nothing. You let the user make the choice.